# How to assign value based on reference in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, reference, associative-array

How do I assign a value to an associative array when I have a reference but cannot hard code the keys?

Situation:
I have an associative array of unknown depth that I must traverse. The end of the branch is an array which I must sum and assign back to that branch.

```
$array = [
    foo => [
        a => [1, 2],
        b => [3, 4]
    ];
$pointer =& $array['foo']['b']; //in live the keys are variable.
$pointer = array_sum($pointer);
```

What I want is `$array` to now look like:

```
[
    foo => [
        a => [1,2],
        b => 7
    ]
]
```

However, the above code creates a new variable `$pointer` with value 7 without changing `$array`. How do I update `$array['foo']['b']` with just the pointer? I can potentially find out the keys involved, but they are variable so I am not sure if that helps.

--EDIT:

User jh1711 pointed out that my code snippet does work. Turns out the problem in my code was just before that where I copied the reference.

This does not work:

```
$pointer =& $mainPointer[$key];
```

This does work:

```
$pointer =& $mainPointer;
$pointer =& $pointer[$key];
```

I'm not really sure why the first fails, but my code works now!

Comment: I get the result you want: https://3v4l.org/gf4bi. Not sure what's different in your full code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the explanation why your first attempt failed. See comments.

Here is the bad code.

```
$array = [
    'foo' => [
    'a' => [1, 2],
    'b' => [3, 4]
    ]
];
$pointer =& $array['foo']['b']; // $pointer now has type array
$pointer = array_sum($pointer); // $pointer now has type integer, so no array assignment
```

Here is the correct code.

```
$pointer =& $array['foo']['b']; // $pointer now has type array
$sum = array_sum($pointer);     // $sum is type integer
$pointer = $sum;                // assign integer $sum to array $pointer
```

This is sneaky old PHP dynamic typing at work. `array_sum();` returns an integer type, and in doing so converted $pointer to an integer type also, thereby preventing the correct array assignment. If in doubt use `gettype($value)` after assignments while debugging.

Comment: @Aurelion. I got fooled by this a few times so I thought was work explaining.